# My Snapstore is not properly showing Apps Images

Tags: ubuntu-store, 20.04

I tried to Update my Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 it updated sucessfully but when i tried to open snapstore snapstore is not showing App's images hence i am unable to explore Apps in Snapstore along with that i am unable to see Ubuntu Store because recently i downloaded a .deb file and when i tried to open it for installation the system was unable to find the appropriate software to install it. please help me in this regard it would very thankful [Snap Store Image in my Ubuntu20.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr5zl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04 is still under development. So, you must have tried the daily build. I hope it will be resolved before the stable release.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is having this problem in any distro, do the following:

1. Close the snap-store gui
2. in the terminal:
   sudo snap refresh --channel=beta snap-store
3. Reboot your system.
4. Start using snap-store with all the images.